# How to add Formatting Options in Edittext - Android?

Tags: android, formatting, format

I have a big Edittext like notepad kind of. I want to put formatting options like this layout itself. For eg:- Bold,Italics, Indent, Bullets,Numbering etc
Please anyone suggest something because i am unable to do this or find any solution or even a hint to this.

I want something like this toolbar only present in this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provided  Class Named `SpannableString` class that have all the main required options for a rich text. you can Use your own Business logic to implement them on the Text with any click able action
for a Basic Tutorial have a look at the following link
[SpannableString](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring)